# DSolve for Second Order Differential

Tags: differential-equations

I have an equation

```
y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0
```

So I'm using DSolve like this:

```
DSolve[{y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == yrad, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]
```

Where `yrad=Pi/9`
I keep getting the `ifun`,`inex`and `bvfail` errors. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks so much

EDIT:
Sorry I just realized I left out `w=1.4`

Comment: I just tried `Simplify@DSolve[{y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == Pi/9, y'[0] == 0}, y[t], t]` (putting in the value of `yrad` manually).  I get `{{y[t] -> -2 JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[2 - (-1)^(1/9) + (-1)^(8/9)] t w - EllipticF[\[Pi]/18, 4/(2 - (-1)^(1/9) + (-1)^(8/9))], 4/(2 - (-1)^(1/9) + (-1)^(8/9))]}}`

Comment: @2012rcampion The OP must be using V9 or earlier, instead of V10.

Comment: When I try that with my `w` plugged in, I continue to get the same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: This is for V9. `DSolve` works in V10**

Consider the general solution:

```
sols = DSolve[{y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0}, y, t]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >>

```
(*
  {{y -> Function[{t},
      -2 JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[(2 w^2 + C[1]) (t + C[2])^2], (4 w^2)/(2 w^2 + C[1])]]},
   {y -> Function[{t}, 
       2 JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[(2 w^2 + C[1]) (t + C[2])^2], (4 w^2)/(2 w^2 + C[1])]]}}
*)
```

It's not particularly easy to solve for the coefficients `C[1]` and `C[2]` for a given IVP.  Perhaps you can figure out how to use it, though?

Given concrete numbers for the parameters, values can be found:

```
cons1 = Block[{w = 1.4},
 FindRoot[{y[0] == Pi/9, y'[0] == 0} /. First[sols] /. 
   Thread[{C[1], C[2]} -> {c1, c2}], {c1, 1}, {c2, 1}]
 ]
```

> FindRoot::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations. >>

```
(*
  {c1 -> -3.93237 + 3.84299*10^-6 I, c2 -> 0.00280231 + 0.0000103908 I}
*)
```

Second solution:

```
cons2 = Block[{w = 1.4},
 FindRoot[{y[0] == Pi/9, y'[0] == 0} /. Last[sols] /. 
   Thread[{C[1], C[2]} -> {c1, c2}], {c1, 1}, {c2, 1}]
 ]
(*
  {c1 -> -3.6836 - 2.3703*10^-16 I, c2 -> 1.1306 + 5.30368*10^-16 I}
*)
```

We should check the solutions.  This is not particularly easy since `JacobiAmplitude` won't be easy to simplify symbolically.  So let's check it numerically.  First the particular solutions produced by the above results of `FindRoot`:

```
sols0 = MapThread[ReplaceAll, {sols, {cons1, cons2}}];
```

Next, we'll check the residuals of the differential equation and the initial conditions:

```
Block[{w = 1.4, yrad = Pi/9},
   {y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == yrad, y'[0] == 0} /. 
      Equal -> Subtract /. sols0 // FullSimplify
   ] /. t -> RandomReal[1, 10] // Chop
(*
{{{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, -0.349067 + 0.000311727 I, 0.0000172797 + 0.111239 I},
 {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 0, 0}}
*)
```

Clearly the first solution does not satisfy the initial conditions.  Therefore only the second solution is valid.

```
Last[sols0]
(*
  {y -> Function[{t}, 
     2 JacobiAmplitude[1/2 Sqrt[(2 w^2 - (3.6836 + 2.02417*10^-17 I)) (t + (1.1306 + 
             1.24204*10^-16 I))^2], (4 w^2)/(2 w^2 - (3.6836 + 2.02417*10^-17 I))]]}
*)
```

---

Note: The hint in one of the error messages suggests trying `Reduce`.  That may be tried using the following:

```
Block[{opts, res},
 opts = Options[Solve];
 SetOptions[Solve, Method -> Reduce];
 res = DSolve[{y''[t] + w^2*Sin[y[t]] == 0, y[0] == yrad, y'[0] == 0},
    y[t], t];
 SetOptions[Solve, opts];
 res
 ]
```

> DSolve::bvimp: General solution contains implicit solutions. In the boundary value problem, these solutions will be ignored, so some of the solutions will be lost. >>

```
(*
  {}
*)
```

Obviously, it is not successful in this case.  By the way, the message here suggested the above method to me.  (So the messages, imo, often contain useful hints.)

Comment: Yeah I guess I'm kinda out of luck because I'm using V9...thanks for your help though!

Comment: @user1985351 You're welcome.  Note that the above gives a solution for any given parameters; in particular for your case.  Is it not clear?

Comment: Yeah I see how you got it, but I think it's a bit above my knowledge of Mathematica though, haha. But again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user1985351 You're welcome.  Note that 2012rcampion's comment contains a valid solution. Even if you cannot compute it with V9, you could copy the formula.