# Validating implicit function solves ODE

Tags: differential-equations

Suppose I want to verify that the function defined by the equation $\frac{\ln x}{y}+\frac{y^2}{2}=0$ solves the differential equation $\frac{y}{x}dx+(y^3-\ln x)dy=0$. How can I do that? I tried:

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == y[x]/(x*(Log[x] - y[x]^3)), y[x], x];
F = Solve[y^2/2 + Log[x]/y == 0, y, MaxExtraConditions -> Automatic];
sol /. F // FullSimplify
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(124954)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124954).  Also related: [(73052)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73052), [(124835)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124835).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, we define the ODE and solution (changing the OP's form with `y` to `y[x]`):

```
ode = y'[x] == y[x]/(x*(Log[x] - y[x]^3))
sol = y^2/2 + Log[x]/y == 0 /. y -> y[x]
(*
  y'[x] == y[x]/(x (Log[x] - y[x]^3))
  Log[x]/y[x] + y[x]^2/2 == 0
*)
```

Optionally, we can get the domain of the ODE and solution:

```
dom = FunctionDomain[{ode, sol} /. Equal -> Subtract, {x, y[x], y'[x]}]
(*  x > 0 && y[x] != 0 && Log[x] - y[x]^3 != 0  *)
```

Then we can eliminate `y'[x]` from the ODE and the derivative of the solution (via implicit differentiation).  The result consists of conditions that are generically true. Optionally we can use the domain above to show that the conditions are true over the domain.

```
Eliminate[{ode, D[sol, x]}, y'[x]]
Simplify[%, dom]
(*
  x != 0 && y[x] != 0 && Log[x] - y[x]^3 != 0
  True
*)
```

(No need to use `DSolve` if verification is the goal.)

Comment: Thank you. But what happens if the implicit function is **not** a solution to the ODE? Will we necessarily get wrong conditions? That is, how can we know that the result is necessarily false? Just curious.

Comment: @user301535 Generally, `Eliminate` will return conditions under which the system is satisfied (`True`). There are two possible issues that come to mind. One is computation feasibility.  Symbolic answers cannot always be computed. One might check numerically as I did [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73054) to select which of two solutions was correct. The second is that a proposed solution might satisfy the ODE over part of its domain but not over all of it. In such a case, the system probably would not simplify down to `True` or `False`. Again, one might check numerically.

Comment: @user301535 For instance, for `sol = y^2 + Log[x]/y == 0 /. y -> y[x]`, the method above returns `False`, which is what should generally happen for non-solutions.